# Android webview app -clickable phone number as item link

Tags: android, android-webview, phone-number

does anyone have idea how to acomplish this:
Load Url which is list of item,normaly when you click on particular item new page is open with details and clickable phone button.Now I would like to show this clcikable phone button on first page for evrey item,so user can dial it from first page without entering secong page(item details),i tought to parse url in background and than just replace item url with clickable phone ,in this case when user click on particular item phone number would dial insted of opening item details url like it is normally.

Comment: Can you handle the redirects on the webpage? if you can redirect your web to a specific url when the user clicks on the phone inside each item of the list, then you can get that url inside shouldOverrideUrlLoading(..). And ask if the url given is the one you put for phone redirect and get the parameters of it (assuming you put the number as a url parameter on your redirect) and create an intent to the Phone class.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: let me know if it helps you, if you want i can make an example for this, just upload some code you have now

Comment: My idea is to parse url for phone number and use it as item link,at this way when user click on item phone call will be lunched.Now I have situation that user have to click on item and open item details page to see clickable phone button,I just want to use this phone number as item link.My idea is to open main url(with list of all items),than parse item urls in background to get phone number and use it as item url ...Goal is to dial phone number from main url(url list) insted to open every item to click on phone button.

Comment: If you upload your code I can modify it to achieve what you need

Comment: I will upload code as soon as I write one,I'm still on design level..in fact I'm c/cpp and php  programmer and recently started with java and android...so I know how to implement this on lowest level...just not sure what approuch to use...fetch data as feed and than parse it and publish in textview....or just use webview and than owerwrite item urls...will publish some code so we can start

Comment: I would recommend to implement the interface in android, its a little bit expensive talking about time, but it worth. Let me see if I have some example to help you